# Fixed navbar, white gap, why?

Tags: html, css

I want to ask you why i get this white gap when i want to do fixed scroll navbar on top ? Do you guys have any sugestion in this situation ? The menu should get on the background image. I have tried to do something with the background but it doesnt help.

Here is the pic of gap:
https://ibb.co/RcvM5nS

And here is the code:

```css
.background {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*menu*/
#siteNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav.scroll {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 80px;
}
#siteNav .logo {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
#siteNav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#siteNav ul li a {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}
#siteNav ul li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
            <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--header-->
        <div class="background">
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1><br><a></a></br>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Comment: What white gap ? does it appear in the code you shared here ?

Comment: Yes it does, look on the pic. I want navbar to be on background img.

Comment: I was asking about the code you shared that should replicate the problem. Not the image. We cannot give you an exact solution if you don't replicate your problem here so we can test it

Comment: Code is the same, changed background to black so i dont need to uplod img for you to see the gap.

Comment: Please don't use an external source for the image. Upload it to the question, rather.

Comment: The problem is with `h1` margin top. Remove that and it will work.
Also i suggest you use `<header>` tag as a first level tag which includes the nav.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Soulution 1 :

Add `padding: 6em 0 3em;` to `<div>` below the `<nav>`

## Soulution 2 :

Get rid of `<h1>`

> The code snippet apply the first solution

```css
.background {
    background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 6em 0 3em;
}
/*menu*/
#siteNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav.scroll {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 80px;
}
#siteNav .logo {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
#siteNav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#siteNav ul li a {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #000000;
}
#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}
#siteNav ul li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
            <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--header-->
        <div class="background">
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1><br><a></a></br>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `h1` margin top. Remove that and it will work.
Also i suggest you use `<header>` tag as a first level tag which includes the nav.

Anyway, here's the solution.

I added `margin:0` to body because here it has a default margin of 8px

```css
.background {
    background-color: #000000;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 650px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*menu*/
#siteNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav.scroll {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 80px;
}
#siteNav .logo {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
#siteNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
#siteNav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#siteNav ul li a {
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 6px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: #ffffff;
}
#siteNav.scroll ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}
#siteNav ul li a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1 {
 margin-top:0;
}

body { 
 margin:0 
}
```

```html
<nav id="siteNav">
            <img class="logo" src="images/img2-logo.png" alt="">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mission">MISSION</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--header-->
        <div class="background">
            <header>
                <div>
                    <h1><br /><a></a>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have used `<h1>` tag in your HTML code and that is having default margins set in it. if you just handle that, it will resolve your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55142485/4646944 explained with code, what I was saying.